# Unique 2D transformation - how to do?

Tags: transforms

This is my first new question, having had many of my questions answered by previous posts. Great resource, thank you for everything you do.

I'm trying to take a simple 2D Cartesian grid and transform it in a very specific way, for an animation, and I cannot figure out how to achieve what I need. (1) The vertical lines need to remain straight but fan out from the top. (2) The left-most vertical line needs to remain vertical, with the vertical lines getting more angled the farther out you go. (3) Meanwhile the horizontal lines need to curve roughly into half-parabolas. (4) If this is done right, every intersection of lines will remain a right angle. The grid cannot shear.

Several years ago, I was able to build a device that accomplished this mechanically. Here are screenshots from the video I used that in, showing what I want to do:

[image]

[image]

I have tried making the lines out of solids, subdividing the horizontal ones, and then trying various ways to proportionally edit the grid. Proportional editing doesn't seem to be the way to go. It's almost like I need a "scale rotationally" or "polar scaling" tool. Having seen the most amazing things done in Blender, I'm sure there's a way to do it.

In case you're curious, the grid represents one dimension of space (vertical) and one of time (horizontal), and the transformation is what happens to spacetime where there's gravity — spacetime gets warped. The name of the original video is "How Gravity Makes Things Fall."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aside from using Python to create it mathematically, I think the best tool for this would be the Lattice Deform Modifier.

I realise my image isn't exactly what you're looking for, but it's just a quick example of what the tool can do.

The green part is a plane with lots of subdivisions, and the white part is the lattice. Once the lattice is linked to the plane, you can move the points of it around until you get the desired result.

https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/deform/lattice.html

[image]

Comment: That works quite well, and good enough for my purposes. With strength being the animated parameter. Thank you.

Comment: Great to hear @EdwardCurrent. Could you please mark the answer as accepted so others can find it too, thanks 